# Minimum Hamiltonian path length using brute force approach

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

**Assumption** At least one Hamiltonian path exists in the graph. I am trying to find minimum path length among all Hamiltonian paths.

**My approach**
Let us say we have three nodes.

**Possible paths are**

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
1 -> 3 -> 2
2 -> 1 -> 3
2 -> 3 -> 1
3 -> 1 -> 2
3 -> 2 -> 1
```

Find path length of all tracks and take minimum among them. Time complexity of this approach will be `O(N*(N!))` where `N = #nodes`

I am getting the wrong answer with this approach. Is the above approach correct? Please help.

Comment: If you're getting the wrong answer by generating all possible answers, then you're either not generating all possible answers or you're calculating the resulting distance incorrectly. We can't tell which one without seeing your code.

Comment: @beaker I finally found that the problem is with the online judge. The approach seems to be correct. Thank you.